# progressive random forest?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I am considering using random forest for a classification problem. The data comes in sequences. I plan to use first N(500) to train the classifier. Then, use the classifier to classify the data after that. It will make mistakes and the mistakes sometimes can be recorded.

My question is: can I use those mis-classified data to retrain the original classifier and how? If I simply add the mis-classified ones to original training set with size N, then the importance of the mis-classified ones will be exaggerated as the corrected classified ones are ignored. Do I have to retrain the classifier using all data? What other classifiers can do this kind of learning?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a basic version of the [Boosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_%28machine_learning%29) meta-algorithm.

It's better if your underlying learner have a natural way to handle samples weights. I have not tried boosting random forests (generally boosting is used on individual shallow decision trees with a depth limit between 1 and 3) but that might work but will likely be very CPU intensive.

Alternatively you can train several independent boosted decision stumps in parallel with different PRNG seed values and then aggregate the final decision function as you would do with a random forests (e.g. voting or averaging class probability assignments).

If you are using Python, you should have a look at the [scikit-learn documentation on the topic](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html).

Disclaimer: I am a scikit-learn contributor.

Comment: I wonder if what windchime means is there is feedback on correctness once the classifier has been deployed, so that new data-points become available for training. Do you then need to perform on-line rather than batch training?

Comment: In that case it's probably much faster to re-train a new model on the sum of all labeled data, taking human corrections into account.

Comment: What jonnydedwards said was what I meant in my question. My concern is improving the classifier after deploying it in production. After user adopts it, I have the chance to receive feedback about its correctness. When it is classifying correctly, user does not say anything. If it mis-classifies, user tells me, sometimes. Then, how do I incorporate those reported mis-classified cases into the classifier?

Comment: You add the corrected labeled data to an aggregate training set and you retrain a new model. However automating the model update and deployment to take user feedback into account automatically might be risky (depending on the kind of application) as malicious user could exploit this feedback loop and game the system by inject a large quantity of poisonous inputs. In that case it might be better to keep a trusted human moderator in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of your problem.

You have a dataset and create two subdata set with it say, training dataset and evaluation dataset. *How can you use the evaluation dataset to improve classification performance ?*

The point of this probleme is'nt to find a better classifier but to find a good way for the evaluation, then have a good classifier in the production environnement.

---

### Evaluation purpose

As the evaluation dataset has been tag for evaluation there is now way yo do this. You must use another way for training and evaluation.

A common way to do is **cross-validation**;

Randomize your samples in your dataset. Create ten partitions from your initial dataset. Then do ten iteration of the following :
    Take all partitions but the n-th for training and do the evaluation with the n-th.

After this take the median of the errors of the ten run. 
This will give you the errors rate of yours classifiers.
The least run give you the worst case.

---

### Production purpose

(no more evaluation)

You don't care anymore of evaluation. So take **all yours samples of all your dataset** and give it for training to your classifier (re-run a complet simple training). The result can be use in production environnement, but can't be evaluate any more with any of yours data. The result is as best as the worst case in previous partitions set.

### Flow sample processing

(production or learning)

When you are in a flow where new samples are produce over time. You will face case where some sample correct errors case. This is the wanted behavior because we want the system to
improve itself. If you just correct in place the leaf in errors, after some times your
classifier will have nothing in common with the original random forest. You will be doing
a form of greedy learning, like [meta taboo search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabu_search). Clearly **we don't wanna this**.

If we try to reprocess all the dataset + the new sample every time a new sample is available we will experiment terrible low latency. The solution is like human, sometime
a background process run (when service is on low usage), and all data get a complet
re-learning; and at the end swap **old and new** classifier.

Sometime the *sleep time* is too short for a complet re-learning. So you have to use node computing clusturing [like that](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36726.html). It cost lot of developpement because you probably need to re-write the algorithms; but at that time you already have the bigest computer you could have found.

*note : Swap process is very important to master. You should already have it in your production plan. What do you do if you want to change algorithms? backup? benchmark? power-cut? etc...*

Comment: My question actually is less about initial cross validation. It is more about after deploying a classifier in production, you also have the chance to receive feedback about its correctness. When it is classifying correctly, user does not say anything. If it mis-classifies, user tells you, sometimes. Then, how should I incorporate the feedback from user into original training?

Comment: Okay I'm adding details for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add the new data and retrain the classifier periodically if it weren't too expensive.

A simple way to keep things in balance is to add weights.

If you weigh all positive samples by 1/n_positive and all negative samples by 1/n_negative ( including all the new negative samples you're getting ), then you don't have to worry about the classifier getting out of balance.